# How to achieve virtual clicks on an android app

Tags: android, c#, gui, visual-studio, touchscreen

I am thinking of making an application or service or an extension that works on top of a game on android. It is required to generate a virtual touch/click on the game screen.

I thought of multiple solutions:

- Downloading BlueStacks and launching the preferred game then creating a c# script using visual studio [How to perform a Virtual Mouse click C# without using a mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146275/how-to-perform-a-virtual-mouse-click-c-sharp-without-using-a-mouse/40307120#40307120)
- Creating an extension like Xmod or apps that appear in small icon above other games, that contain settings and simple functions.

All I want to do is to open my game, open the tool (VirtualClicker) and set a function that clicks on the screen according to a time array. For eg:`TimeToClick[0,4.3,5.6]` this will click on the screen considering the initial time when the user does something(initiate program using an icon) and at ***t=0sec, t=4.3sec, t=5.6sec*** the program will perform a virtual click to the game screen.

What tools to use for this?